# How do I do a GET request with multiple headers?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

Syntax Error when trying to put multiple headers into my `GET` Request.

I've tried changing the '' around Content-Type and Authorization to "", because I've seen posts on here involving both of them, but neither seem to work. Here is my code.

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://api.website.com/testpost'
headers = {

        'Content-type': 'application/json'
        'Authorization': 'Bearer placeholdertoken'
}
response= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

I am supposed to be getting an answer, but I'm getting a syntax error at the ":" after authorization

Answer (score 3):

You’ve not put commas after your key value pairs

Answer (score 1):

```
headers = {

        'Content-type': 'application/json'
        'Authorization': 'Bearer placeholdertoken'
}
```

That is not correct syntax for creating the dictionary.. you are missing a comma between the `key: value` pairs.

Update your code to add a comma, like this:

```
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer placeholdertoken'
}
```